# Accelerated Video Compression

Tags: video, compression, gpu

What is a GPU/software combination that does efficient/high-speed conversion from Motion JPEG to any high-compression/high-quality codec without using a lot of CPU?

I'm working on a dSLR video workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately x264 – which is probably one of the fastest h.264 encoders out there – has no GPU acceleration yet. There's a "nice" [forum discussion](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/325748-x264-soon-to-be-gpu-accelerated) about it.

However, researchers at Uni Heidelberg have [implemented x264 with OpenCL support](http://li5.ziti.uni-heidelberg.de/x264gpu/), but I haven't tried this yet. You might want to give it a shot, it also has some examples. Can't try it here because I'm on a Mac.

Apart from that, you will probably need a newer Intel processor and an NVIDIA graphics card because of the proprietary CUDA implementation. I found two pieces of software for this:

[**MediaCoder**](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/)

is actually free.

> Hardware encoding acceleration (nVidia CUDA & Intel Media SDK)

[**Badaboom**](http://www.badaboomit.com/)

comes at $40, but doesn't really seem to provide acceptable quality (I've read this in some forums)

> And with it comes new features, high-end performance, premium video quality, and graphics acceleration via the latest NVIDIA and Intel hardware!

---

That all being said, I wonder if these tools actually work with Motion JPEG as input. Doesn't seem so straight from the feature list, but you might just want to give it a shot.

Comment: too bad mediacoder isn't open source...